# Find and replace special characters in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a number of Windows based **.m3u** playlists - they start with `..\..\` and have `\` instead of `/` for folder paths, whereas Ubuntu prefers they start with `/media/usr/part/dir/` (i.e. the absolute path).

I want to make the following changes

1. Replace all `..\..\` with `/media/usr/part/dir/`
2. Replace all `\` with `/`

I tried using `find /home/user/directory -name \*.m3u -exec sed -i "s/\.\.\\\.\.\/\/media\/usr\/part\/dir\//g" {} \;` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files/84013#84013), and tried using `_` and `:` as delimiters as suggested [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1).

However, I keep getting

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
```

How do I make the necessary replacements in my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/\.\.\\\.\.\/\/media\/usr\/part\/dir\//g
```

This `sed` command is wrong, because it has a missing `\` before the first `/`, which leads the preceding `\` to escape it as a literal `/` (changing the pattern and "eating" the separator) and, for the purpose of replacing a single occurence of `..\..\` on each line, it has an excessive `g` switch at the end; in any case it's missing the replacement of the `\` characters with the `/` character part.

Use this one instead; I've took the liberty of changing the separator to get rid of a likely sudden [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) and to change `;` with `+` to improve the command's performance over a huge number of files:

```
find /home/user/directory -name \*.m3u -exec sed -i 's|\.\.\\\.\.\\|/media/usr/part/dir/|; s|\\|/|g' {} \+
```

Output:

```
~/tmp$ cat playlist1.m3u 
..\..\path1
stuff
..\..\path2\path2
stuff
..\..\path3\path3\path3
stuff
~/tmp$ find . -name \*.m3u -exec sed -i 's|\.\.\\\.\.\\|/media/usr/part/dir/|; s|\\|/|g' {} \+
~/tmp$ cat playlist1.m3u 
/media/usr/part/dir/path1
stuff
/media/usr/part/dir/path2/path2
stuff
/media/usr/part/dir/path3/path3/path3
stuff
```

Comment: worked like charm. Thanks !

I had no idea `sed` replacemets could be given on the same line in a python-ish manner. And I don't need to use `//` when I want to replace a frontslash (i.e. `/` char) in the file ?

Comment: @3l4ng Usually yes (but not with a slash, with a backslash) because usually slashes are used as the separator, and if not escaped when used as a literal `/` they are interpreted as the separator (much like it happened with your command): I changed the separator to `|` exactly because of that, because using `/` would have lead to this (less intelligible) command: `s/\.\.\\\.\.\\/\/media\/usr\/part\/dir\//; s/\\/\//g`