# command line find replace strings with quotations

Tags: command-line

[Find and replace text within multiple files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files/84013#84013?newreg=57ec0d1015e146a194d3d54c324ddad0)

I found the above answer for finding and replacing regular strings, but it doesn't work with say replacing `"none"` with `"Unitless"` due to the syntax of the command.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to change the outer quotes to single quotes:

```
sed 's/"none"/"Unitless"/g'
```

IMHO it's better to use single-quotes anyhow for literal strings - unless you need the double quote functionality specifically (for example, when using a shell variable in the pattern or replacement text).

Alternatively, escape the literal quotes: `"s/\"none\"/\"Unitless\"/g"`

Comment: @ThomasKirven If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.