# Using find to edit multiple files in multiple directories (that are in consistent form)

Tags: command-line, bash, find

what I a trying to do is to use find to edit/replace string in multiple files with same name in multiple directories with consistent form

multiple files:

```
status1_cap
```

multiple directories:

```
/home/user/directory/subdirectory1
/home/user/directory/subdirectory2
/home/user/directory/subdirectory3
...
```

I looked at these resources:

[Find and replace text within multiple files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files?newreg=ebb2aba0d5ec4a109f15798327acd8b5)

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/find-how-search-multiple-folders-directories-unix/

But the solutions are not exactly the same.

I was thinking something like this would work?:

`find /home/user/directory/subdirectory{*} -name \status1_cap.txt -exec sed -i "s/cap=1/cap=2/g" {} \;`

Is there a way a one line cmd that could do this?

Comment: Do you really need `find` here? if you know where all the files are, a simple shell glob like `/home/user/directory/*/status1_cap` should suffice

Comment: @steeldriver hm I dont really feel comfortable that it would be going thru all files...thats why...